# C++ use SSL to ensure Winsock TCP data security on Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, security, ssl, tcp

We have a C\S application which is developed on Windows. The development language is C\C++ and use the Winsock (TCP) library. Now the fundamental function is finished. Because the server side works in the internet, we must ensure the data security. After search on the internet, we found the **SSL** can help. And there is an article on the Codeproject:[CSslSocket - SSL/TLS enabled CSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1600/CSslSocket-SSL-TLS-enabled-CSocket), which shows how to use the windows Schannel to implement the SSL for MFC CSocket。

Also I noticed the implement need a **Certificate**. For our application, we don't have the **Certificate**.

1. Do we need to apply for a **Certificate** and how to apply? Or any simple solution to implement the SSL in our case (we want to use Windows SSPI, not other open source library, like OpenSSL).
2. Is there any other common solution to ensure the TCP socket data security except for the SSL?
   Thanks!

Comment: There is no such language as 'C/C++'. One or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You don't strictly *need* a certificate, but you *should* use one, at least on the server side, so clients can validate that they are not connected to the incorrect server, like a MITM attacker.  Certificates are not usually used on the client side, though they can be, if the server wants to validate clients are who they say they are.

Yes, there are other options besides SSL/TLS.  For example, [WinSock Secure Socket Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394815.aspx).  Or you can simply encrypt/decrypt your socket data manually using any encryption engine/library you want.  SSL/TLS is more than just encryption, it is a whole bi-directional communication protocol, and it is widely supported on most platforms, so you *should* use it.

Comment: Thank you! 
Yes, the server side should use a certificate. But I don't know  which one to use. Please help!

Comment: There are plenty of cheap/commercial SSL certificate providers available.  Or you can use *self-signed* certificates (if you don't need the stricter security guarantees that a paid certificate provides).  There is tons of information about this topic if you look around.